# How to add List item using javascript with anonymus access in SharePoint Online?

Tags: 2013, infopath, sharepoint-online, public-website

I have a public site and I want to add a 'Subscribe Us' box to it, where anonymous users will enter there email addresses.

This address will be added to a list and workflows should trigger emails.

So is it possible to add list items using JavaScript with anonymous access in SharePoint Online?

I tried InfoPath forms but it is not working without logging in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, its the app that you created that requires access to app content.